# php - display a table row by row

Tags: php

I print my table like that:

```
print $tableHeader . $dataRow . $tableFooter;
```

the $dataRow is the result of a loop (getting data from DB and building the row, nothing unusual), it's something like:

```
while ($obj = mysql_fetch_object($res)) { 
  $dataRow .= ' <td width="210" style="...">' . $obj->title . ' <br /> '. $obj->screenName .' </td>';
  ...
  ...
}
```

The problem is when there is a huge amount of information to handle => huge amount of rows to build before displaying the final table.

How could I tell Apache to display it row by row ?

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](http://j.mp/XqV7Lp). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which.

Comment: apache has nothing to do with this. All you need is a proper pagination system.

Comment: If php assigns its variables, Apache can't help because it does not see variables. Use `echo` instead, if you can.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it with Ajax.

1. You can make a pagination. When you click on a page, you load only the x results.
2. You can trigger the user's scroll and load more results.

I personnally use DataTables which can do the two things : http://www.datatables.net/

Hope that helps !

Answer (score 0):

Can't you paginate?

the way to go is to tell php to display piece by piece, but you will have to change your code a bit to something like.

```
print $tableHeader 
while ($obj = mysql_fetch_object($res)) { 
   print ' <td width="210" style="...">' . $obj->title . ' <br /> '. $obj->screenName .' </td>';
  flush();
}
print $tableFooter;
```